# TOR: hide my site in clearweb‏

Tags: apache-2.2, tor

I have launched a website in TOR and I can access it through the .onion address and also typing the ip of my server in my browser.  I want my site was only accessible from TOR and not through clearweb, how can I achieve this?

I'm using Ubuntu 12 and Apache2

Comment: Have a look at https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html.en for Hidden Services Configuration and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html for some  Apache VirtualHost Examples.

Answer (score 8):

To run a Tor hidden service using Apache which is not accessible from the public network, be sure that Apache is configured to listen only on the local interface (e.g. 127.0.0.1).

Some things you may need to change in your configuration files are:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

and

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
```

You can verify the IP addresses that Apache is bound to by running the `ss` command:

```
ss -tnlp
```