# How do I only serve on localhost through apache2?

Tags: http, localhost, tor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TOR: hide my site in clearweb‏](https://serverfault.com/questions/410121/tor-hide-my-site-in-clearweb)

I'm trying to serve on localhost only but every time I find a way to do it, it always says to edit http.d I cannot find http.d. Can someone tell me a good way to setup apache to serve ONLY on localhost? Please include paths on the default Ubuntu install. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Open /etc/apache2/ports.conf

Change the "Listen" entry to look like this:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

You will need to restart apache after that:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```